# Android MediaRecorder saving video to buffer

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I would like to be able to gain some control of the MediaRecorder write capabilities, what I want is to be able to build a pause functionality while recording from the camera but currently this method does not exist in the class, so what I want to do to achieve this is to save the output to a buffer and then I choose when it writes or doesnt write, how can this best be done?

EDIT: Here is my attempt at doing this but could not get it to work

```
private FileDescriptor getStreamFd() {
    ParcelFileDescriptor pipe = null;
    try {

        Calendar calendarTime = Calendar.getInstance();

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                String.valueOf(calendarTime.getTimeInMillis()) + ".mp4");

        pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file,
                ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_CREATE
                        | ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_APPEND
                        | ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(FileDescriptor.in);

        while (usecamera) {

                      if(recordng){
                        out.write(buf, 0, len);
                      }

        }

        is.close();
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception opening pipe", e);
    }

    return pipe.getFileDescriptor();
}
```

Comment: write in different file and add them.little bit complex.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I attempted to write something like this over the weekend but it didnt work, would you be able to give me a clue as to how this can be changed to accomplish this?